# Javascript - Leaving out a value?

Tags: javascript, arrays

My fields are inputting:

```
List1_1=test
List1_2=
List1_3=
```

etc...

My code currently returns:

```
filter=[["test","","",""],["","","",""],["","",""]]
```

I need it to return:

```
filter=[["test"]]
```

Other times there are more, for example:

```
List1_1=test
List1_2=test
List1_3=test
List1_4=test
List2_1=test
List2_2=test
List2_3=
List2_4=
List3_1=test
List3_2=
List3_3=
List3_4=
```

The return should be:

```
filter=[["test","test","test","test"],["test","test"],["test"]]
```

But is currently returning:

```
filter=[["test","test","test","test"],["test","test","",""],["test","","",""]]
```

I need to add javascript that leaves out the extra commas, quotes and brackets. Does anyone have suggestions of how to do this?

Here is my code:

```
function init() {

    if (window.location.href.split("?")[1] != undefined) {

        // example http://sampleurl.com?list1_1=test&list1_2=this&list2_1=that
        url = parse_query_string(window.location.href.split("?")[1]);

        searchQueryString = "filter=["

        // FIRST LIST OF OR'ed KEYWORDS
        if (url.list1_1 != undefined){
            searchQueryString += "["

            searchQueryString += '"'+url.list1_1+'"'
            searchQueryString += (url.list1_2 != undefined? ","+'"'+url.list1_2+'"' : '');
            searchQueryString += (url.list1_3 != undefined? ","+'"'+url.list1_3+'"' : '');
            searchQueryString += (url.list1_4 != undefined? ","+'"'+url.list1_4+'"' : '');
            searchQueryString += "]"
        } 

        // AND ... SECOND LIST OF OR'ed KEYWORDS
        if (url.list2_1 != undefined){
            searchQueryString += ",["

            searchQueryString += '"'+url.list2_1+'"';
            searchQueryString += (url.list2_2 != undefined? ","+'"'+url.list2_2+'"' : '');
            searchQueryString += (url.list2_3 != undefined? ","+'"'+url.list2_3+'"' : '');
            searchQueryString += url.list2_4 != undefined? ","+'"'+url.list2_4+'"' : '';
            searchQueryString += "]"
        } 

        // AND ... THIRD LIST OF OR'ed KEYWORDS
        if (url.list3_1 != undefined){
            searchQueryString += ",["

            searchQueryString += '"'+url.list3_1+'"';
            searchQueryString += (url.list3_2 != undefined? ","+'"'+url.list3_2+'"' : '');
            searchQueryString += (url.list3_3 != undefined? ","+'"'+url.list3_3+'"' : '');
            searchQueryString += url.list3_4 != undefined? ","+'"'+url.list3_4+'"' : '';
            searchQueryString += "]"
        } 

        searchQueryString += "]"
    }
}
```

Comment: it's still the same question from yesterday without some explanation what do you have and what do you want. btw, if you use variables with numbers, take an array instead.

Comment: @NinaScholz It's not optimal but all relevant info is in the question. The input (querystring with `List<x>_<y>=<value>` key-value-pairs), the expected output (an array for each "List" from the querystring without empty values wrapped in an array).

Answer (score 0):

You could split the string, take the search part, split by ampersand and iterate all key/value pairs.

From this pairs get the key and value and from the key the indices for the result set.

```js
var string = 'http://sampleurl.com?list1_1=test&list1_2=this&list2_1=that',
    result = [];
    
string
    .split('?')[1]
    .split('&')
    .forEach(s => {
        var [key, value] = s.split('='),
            [i, j] = key.match(/\d+/g).map(v => v - 1);

        result[i] = result[i] || [];
        result[i][j] = value;
    });

console.log(result);
```